# Putting WKT to MAPINFOW.prj file?

Tags: coordinate-system, mapinfo

I have this WKT file:

```
PROJCS["PRS92 / Philippines zone 3"
,GEOGCS["PRS92"
,DATUM["D_Phillipine_Reference_System_1992"
,SPHEROID["Clarke_1866",6378206.4,294.9786982138982]]
,PRIMEM["Greenwich",0]
,UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]]
,PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"]
,PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0]
,PARAMETER["central_meridian",121]
,PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.99995]
,PARAMETER["false_easting",500000]
,PARAMETER["false_northing",0]
,UNIT["Meter",1]]
```

How can I use it in mapinfo .prj file so that i can use the CRS?
I'm very new in this kind of matter.

Comment: You'll need to add more information.  You have a WKT file with a coordinate system.  Do you have vector data that is not associated with a coordinate system?  Or do you want to draw new data in that coordinate system?

Comment: I want to draw in that coordinate system.

Comment: How is this "unclear"? MapInfo uses a proprietary projection format that doesn't speak to anything, a way to convert them to WKT for Arc or QGIS would be quite useful.

Answer (score 3):

You should add these 2 lines to MapInfow.prj file:

```
"--- Philippines Coordinate Systems ---"
"PRS92 / Philippines zone 3", 8, 50, 7, 121, 0, 0.99995, 500000, 0
```

Add the lines just before "Polish coo..." and you will get it listed alphabetically in MapInfo.

8 = Transverse_Mercator, 50 = D_Phillipine_Reference_System_1992, 7 = Meter as unit. The rest are your parameters. You can look it up in the MapInfo documentation.